# NDEF tag emulation

Tags: embedded, nfc, apdu

I'm trying to emulate an NDEF tag on an abstract embedded system so, I have questions about NFC technology.
Why some NFC chips can't emulate NDEF tags?
If my chip doesn't support a card emulation, can I hack it somehow to fake it by using APDU commands?

Comment: The question is very abstract and needs more focus and details. But one point NDEF are not Tags, it is a data format with standard implementation methods on NFC Forum standards compliant NFC Tags 1 to 5. Not all NFC chips compliant to the NFC standards, thus some cannot support NDEF data format or they can using propitiatory encoding methods (Mifare Classic as an example)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to emulate an NFC tag 4 by using NFC chip of my device but tech support of a chip manufacturer says that a chip isn't support this but they support ISO7816-4. I don't know how can it be.

Comment: Without the make and model of the NFC chip you are using it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Manufacturer says this is a MH1608. And that's all...

Comment: But I have not found this chip. I think it can be an CR95HF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a CR95HF then a quick read of the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cr95hf.pdf) because I've not used this particular chip before, suggest that like other chips I've seen that it is true that it does not support ISO7816-4 because it is not designed to work at that high level protocol level.

If you look at the [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-field_communication#/media/File:NFC_Protocol_Stack.png) it's working at the "protocol" level which is one level below ISO7816-4 which is fine, it can transmit/receive data at the NFC A/B protocol level but it is up to the Host's CPU to decode the raw frame data in to ISO7816-4 commands and data.

But this is not your problem, even at the lower protocol level it does not seem to be able to handle both sides on the communication.

I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/65659726/2373819 as it give some background to hardware capabilities, as the datasheet says it's "Operating modes supported:– Reader/Writer" then it is only an "initiator" and I see no signs that it can be a "target" and therefore it cannot emulate any Tags.

So in short that hardware is not capable of emulating any type of NFC Tag