# Android detect MiFare reader and send data

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I've recently bought a MiFare reader as a project for automating my household a little further. The idea was to make an android app, which talks to a server inside the house, and provide rolling keys in order to emit those via NFC to the reader. From either a phone or a watch.

I've recently started to wonder if it is possible for android to detect the reader itself, and open a NFC intent (brewed android app) in order to send the key to the reader. Just like happens with Google Pay. Phone detects terminal, starts app intent, transmits data.

Is it possible for such device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes some (but not all) NFC readers can behave as if they were an specific type of NFC Tag. Thus Android can detect them and read/write data to them.

But as you don't specify the exact model of the reader it is hard to say the particular reader you have is capable of doing this.

If you look at a similar [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65659726/2373819) it gives some background and in that case the reader was not capable of behaving in the right manner.