# How to read an NFC 'TAG' in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

Looking at what little documentation there is out there, including fairly sparse documentation and the few code examples I could find, I implemented the following Activity that is supposed to pick up a simple text message from another Android device that has an [application installed on it](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc&hl=it&gl=US&pli=1) that allows texting via NFC.

```
const val MIME_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Inizializzazione del NfcAdapter
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)


        // Verifica se il dispositivo supporta l'NFC
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "NFC non supportato!")
            // Il dispositivo non supporta l'NFC
            binding.nfcStatusText.text = "No NFC on this device."
        } else {
            // Imposta il click listener per il pulsante NFC
            binding.nfcButton.setOnClickListener {
                // Avvia l'attivazione dell'NFC
                enableNfc()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun enableNfc() {
        Log.w(TAG, "Abilito l'NFC...", )
        // Controlla se l'NFC è abilitato sul dispositivo
        if (!nfcAdapter?.isEnabled!!) {
            // Se l'NFC è disabilitato, mostra un messaggio all'utente per attivarlo
            binding.nfcStatusText.text = "Turn On NFC"
        } else {
            // L'NFC è già abilitato, attende il rilevamento del dispositivo NFC
            binding.nfcStatusText.text = "Searching..."
        }
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)

        // also reading NFC message from here in case this activity is already started in order
        // not to start another instance of this activity
        receiveMessageFromDevice(intent)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        // foreground dispatch should be enabled here, as onResume is the guaranteed place where app
        // is in the foreground
        enableForegroundDispatch(this, this.nfcAdapter)
        receiveMessageFromDevice(intent)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        disableForegroundDispatch(this, this.nfcAdapter)
    }

    private fun receiveMessageFromDevice(intent: Intent) {
        val action = intent.action
//        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED == action) {
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED == action || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED == action || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED == action) {

            val ndefMessage = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)
            Log.d(TAG, "Parcelables data: $ndefMessage")

            if (!ndefMessage.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                val ndefRecord = (ndefMessage[0] as NdefMessage).records[0]
                val message = ndefRecord.payload.decodeToString()
                binding.nfcStatusText.text = "Message from tag NFC: $message"
            } else {
                binding.nfcStatusText.text = "No message on tag NFC"
            }
        }
    }


    // Foreground dispatch holds the highest priority for capturing NFC intents
    // then go activities with these intent filters:
    // 1) ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED
    // 2) ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED
    // 3) ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED

    // always try to match the one with the highest priority, cause ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED is the most
    // general case and might be intercepted by some other apps installed on your device as well

    // When several apps can match the same intent Android OS will bring up an app chooser dialog
    // which is undesirable, because user will most likely have to move his device from the tag or another
    // NFC device thus breaking a connection, as it's a short range

    private fun enableForegroundDispatch(activity: AppCompatActivity, adapter: NfcAdapter?) {

        // here we are setting up receiving activity for a foreground dispatch
        // thus if activity is already started it will take precedence over any other activity or app
        // with the same intent filters

        val intent = Intent(this, javaClass)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        val filters = arrayOfNulls<IntentFilter>(1)
        val techList = arrayOf<Array<String>>()

        filters[0] = IntentFilter()
        with(filters[0]) {
            this?.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)//ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED
            this?.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
            try {
                this?.addDataType(MIME_TEXT_PLAIN)
            } catch (ex: IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException) {
                throw RuntimeException("Check your MIME type")
            }
        }

        adapter?.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList)
    }

    private fun disableForegroundDispatch(activity: AppCompatActivity, adapter: NfcAdapter?) {
        adapter?.disableForegroundDispatch(activity)
    }
}
```

The problem is that the application I installed on the second Android device to write to this device gives me an error and does not allow me to write to that device.

I don't understand what is wrong with my code also I put the following permissions in the manifest and declared the following intent filter:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you don't understand how NFC works, there are various modes that NFC hardware works in and you are trying to get two incompatible modes to communicate with each other.

Some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65659037/passing-rfid-data-from-iphone-to-a-rc522/65659726#65659726)

Basically you have both devices in Reader/Writer mode, when one device needs to be in Reader/Writer mode and the other in Host Card Emulation Mode.

I would checkout https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid as that is a sample app to turn one of the devices in to HCE mode.