Flutter NFC manager
There is a task to make an application on one device create data to read this NFC data on another device.
As I understand it, I need to write tags on the first device, and read them on the second.
My second device reads bank card data perfectly, but it can't read anything from the first device.
First device :
void _ndefWrite() {
NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
  NdefMessage message = NdefMessage([
    NdefRecord.createText('Hello World!'),
  ]);

  var ndef = Ndef.from(tag);
  if (ndef == null || !ndef.isWritable) {
    final formattable = NdefFormatable.from(tag);
    await formattable?.format(message);
    result.value = 'Tag is not ndef writable';
    NfcManager.instance.stopSession(errorMessage: result.value);
    return;
  }
  try {
    await ndef.write(message);
    result.value = 'Success to "Ndef Write"';
    NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
  } catch (e) {
    result.value = e;
    NfcManager.instance.stopSession(errorMessage: result.value.toString());
    return;
  }
});

}
Second device:
 void _tagRead() {
NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
  result.value = tag.data;
  NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
});

}
Use packege nfc_manager and implementing similar examples, it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.  Maybe I don't understand this technology correctly, please help me

"it doesn't work and I can't figure out why". First post what you tried

Sorry for the incomplete information, I added

I would read the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65659726/2373819 as this will help you understand the technology and why what you are trying does not work and point you to the solution (if it is possible with your selected device platforms)
